# Command to move text cursor

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, cursor

I am looking for a terminal command or script or program which moves the text cursor in whichever text field currently has focus. Something like:

```
move_cursor 1
```

which would move the cursor one column to the right. The reason is that I would like to define keyboard shortcuts which execute this command so I can have keyboard control of the cursor.

Since I am using this with keyboard shortcuts, keyboard event solutions won't work, for example

```
xdotool key --clearmodifiers Right
```

in principle does what I am asking, but since the command will be executed when other keys are depressed, it doesn't really work well.

The behavior I am looking for is similar to the GTK+ Keybinding Theme setting (`org.gnome.desktop.interface.gtk-key-theme`) which can be set to `'Emacs'` so that, for example, `ctrl-f` moves the cursor right one column, `ctrl-b` moves back one column, `ctrl-d` deletes the character to the right of the cursor, etc. I just want different keybindings.

Comment: Hi, you want to achieve this while Emacs option is on or off?

Comment: Preferably off, unless I can just replace the emacs keybindings with my own.

Comment: Ok, and what are the exact key combination you want to use for moving the cursor to right and left?

Comment: I Just made a custom shortcut with Alt+a `xdotool sleep 0.3 key Right` it worked.. but i know sleep time is a big negative here..

Comment: I've remapped capslock to the hyper key, and the key combination would be '<hyper>+f'

Comment: I've just discovered autokey, and it seems to be doing exactly what I need. I'll post as a solution once I have it all figured out.

Comment: Oh, nice.. you got it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a solution using [Autokey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey). Install and open the autokey GUI and create a new phrase, name it whatever you want. In the main field, enter the system key combination that achieves your goal, then set your hotkey using the button at the bottom of the GUI. For example, I've mapped my capslock key to the hyper key using `xmodmap`, so my shortcuts are as follows...

Some examples:

Move cursor right: `<right>` (shortcut: `<hyper>+f`)

Move cursor left: `<left>` (shortcut: `<hyper>+b`)

Delete next word: `<ctrl>+<delete>` (shortcut: `<hyper>+<shift>+d`)

Move to beginning of line: `<home>` (shortcut: `<hyper>+a`)

Delete line to the right of the cursor: `<ctrl>+<end><delete>` (shortcut: `<hyper>+k`)

Use your imagination!